# ng-model not providing the changed value

Tags: angularjs

I have change the value input of my dom element using jquery code in materialize js plugin :

```
 $input.val($(this).attr('id').trim());
```

I am not getting the `ng-model` value in my controller, but getting  value in `POST` form.

I need the implicit value on input value change.

How can I achieve this.

Please advice using the code.

Comment: Please explain your question with sufficient code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run

`$scope.$apply();`

after changing the value... to start the `$digest` cycle.

After changing the value outside of angular scope you need to bring the changes to angular...